# Checking for independence against known probability in survey.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**"77, 882 people were surveyed. 36.2% agree with the statement "Men should have more right to a job than women." 13.8% have a university degree or higher, and 3.6% people fit both criteria.**

**QUESTION:Does it appear that the event that someone agrees with the statement is independent of the event that they have a university degree or higher?"**

I do not understand why the solution involves applying the product rule on 36.2% and 13.8% and then equating it to 3.6%?

I know the product rule, but how is equating it to 3.6% a test of independence?

Comment: Also, which of these probabilities is correct? The probability in question which is 0.036 or 0.05?

Answer (score 0):

The Multiplication Rule that states $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$ works **if and only if** events $A$ and $B$ are independent.

So if we let $P(A)$ be the $36.2$% that agreed with the statement, $P(B)$ be the $13.8$% that have a university degree, and $P(A \cap B)$ be the $3.6$% that fit both criteria, we can plug these values into the equation above. If both sides of the equation are equal, then we say the events are independent.

Comment: This is good. However, I need to understand this:

after we have plugged it in, and we find out that these two are not equal and our answer is not equal to 3.6%, what does it mean for the 3.6%? Is it an incorrect value? Is the survey wrong? Why did they say 3.6% if the product rule says otherwise?

Comment: Excellent question. There is nothing wrong with the 3.6%, as it is still the percentage that fit both criteria, and there is nothing wrong with the survey. The reasoning for this is because of a concept known as [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability). What is happening is basically this: because these events are not independent, if we already know whether or not a given person agrees with the statement, it will actually influence the chances of whether or not they have a degree.

Comment: In general, the multiplication rule is as follows: $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B | A)$. If the events are independent, we can substitue $P(B)$ for $P(B | A)$.

Comment: **..if we already know whether or not a given person agrees with the statement, it will actually influence the chances of whether or not they have a degree.**

How does agreeing or disagreeing with the statement influence the chance of them having  a degree. Them having  a degree doesn't have a degree of subjectivity; they either have it or they don't. It is the opinion that is subjective, no?

I still don't intuitively follow the equating part. I know the laws and formulae, but I can't understand how this is a test of independence.